# Remove clicked value from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `react-admin` framework. I am trying to dynamically remove value from `state` (id), if the value is in the `state` present more than once. My use case is to create checkboxes, so if one checkbox is clicked twice it deselects.

So far I have this code:

```
private addIdsToObj = (id: any) => {
   const Ids = [...this.state.selectedIds, id];
   this.setState({ selectedIds: Ids });
   if (Object.values(this.state.selectedIds).includes(id) === true) {
      const index = this.state.selectedIds.indexOf(id);
      if (index > -1) {
           const newState = this.state.selectedIds.splice(index, 1);
           this.setState({ selectedIds: newState });
      }
   }
}
```

But it behaves weirdly. Right now it only removes every value from the `state` apart from the clicked one, that should be removed in the first place. I am really stuck with this.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Issue you are getting is that const newState = this.state.selectedIds.splice(index, 1); has newState with the removed value. 

const newState = [...this.state,selectedIds];
newState.splice(index, 1);
this.setState({ selectedIds: newState });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the underlying problem is with this line:

`const newState = this.state.selectedIds.splice(index, 1);`

The `splice` method will return the removed element (here newState)

then in the next line, you're setting the state to that value (which the single removed state)

What you should do instead, since `splice` method will remove the element from the source array is to pass `selectedIds` to setState() method

`this.setState({ selectedIds: this.state.selectedIds });`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I cant believe that I spend so much time debugging the code and didnt come across this. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Don't try to mutate the state directly, use `slice(index)` instead of `splice()` to return an array. `const newState = this.state.selectedIds.slice(index);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all since the `setState()` is asynchronous, you should pass the following code inside a callback function, and since `selectedIds` is an array you don't need to use `Object.values()` on it (Because `Object.values()` returns an array of values of an object), `this.state.selectedIds.includes(id)` is enough. In addition, `includes()` return a `true` or `false`, so don't need to check its strict equality. Also, you should use `slice()` instead of splice, because `splice()` return an array of removed element. So your code should be something like this:

```
private addIdsToObj = (id: any) => {
    const Ids = [...this.state.selectedIds, id];
    this.setState({ selectedIds: Ids }, () => { // Put following code inside a callback function
        if (this.state.selectedIds.includes(id)) { // I removed `===` because includes() return true or false
            const index = this.state.selectedIds.indexOf(id);
            if (index > -1) {
                const newState = this.state.selectedIds.slice(index);
                this.setState({ selectedIds: newState });
            }
        }
    });
}
```